# Getting Sub sites in top_navigation in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a site on share Point which contains some sub sites as well.I deployed my APP on main Site, I didn't include sub sites in top navigation but when I am using following code , it gives me Top Navigation bar as well as sub sites. I just want only top navigation not the sub sites how can I exclude sub site.

```
function getTopMenuBar() {

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {

        parent_web = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb();
        navigation = parent_web.get_navigation();
        clientContext.load(navigation);
        quickLaunchNodeCollection = navigation.get_topNavigationBar();
        clientContext.load(quickLaunchNodeCollection);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadingNavigation), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }
}

function OnLoadingNavigation() {
    var nodeEnumerator = this.quickLaunchNodeCollection.getEnumerator();
    while(nodeEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var node = nodeEnumerator.get_current();
}
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    // Some Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the property "Display this site on the top link bar of the parent site?" has been set to true when creating a sub site. If this property of the sub sites is set to false, they won't appear in the top navigation bar of the parent site.

Comment: I set this property as NO while creating sub site. My App is on Parent Site not in sub site I am not getting sub site in menu on main site but by using following code I am getting sub site in menu in my APP